# Azure Functions - DateTime parsing "d/MM/yyyy h:mm tt"

Tags: azure, function, datetime

I've got string in format e.g. `"2/09/2020 12:14 PM"`

When I use it in C# code: `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/MM/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"))` everything goes well. But when date string's day is above 9 e.g. `"22/09/2020 12:14 PM"` I got message `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` In any other enviorment parsing goes well except on Azure Functions. I tried also `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` without luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not able to see a similar behavior at my end. 
https://github.com/Svijay-msft/AzureFunctions/blob/master/SimpleFunction.cs. 
Created a simple function to get the month back. wanted quickly check whether there is any difference from what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try double 'd' instead of one:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"))
```